# Grails error handler always receives null pointer

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, error-handling

We have a custom error controller that gets called after all of our errors.  However, most of our errors that get thrown end up coming into the controller as null pointers, even though the original error was not a null pointer.  Any ideas?  Code below.  Bootstrap and UrlMappings available if needed.  Thanks

Error Handler method

```
def HandleErrors =
{

    def exception = request.exception.cause.class  

    if (exception) 
    { 
        Exception ex = request.exception  //This exception is always a NPE
            ...
```

Block of code throwing the exception.  I originally did not have a try catch in here, but wanted to add it so that I was sure the exception being thrown was Not a NPE.  Its a file not found exception.

```
try{
        def writer = new FileWriter( new File(fileSaveLocation));
    } 
    catch ( ex)
    {
        throw(ex)
    }
```

Edit: Adding the exception that is pushed to the exception handler

```
Exception:org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException
Cause:org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not because you're referencing something that is null inside the error handler, and so are inadvertently throwing another exception, which is again caught?

can you try changing:

```
def exception = request.exception.cause.class
```

to

```
def exception = request?.exception?.cause?.class
```

Comment: I made the change and exception is still set to org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException rather than null, so it appears to not be inadvertently throwing/catching a second exception.

Comment: Does putting `grails.util.GrailsUtil.sanitize(request.exception)).printStackTrace()` at the top of the `HandleErrors` method print the cause location of the NPE to the console?

Comment: Actually, the issue turned out to be how the BootStrap file was set up.  I'm still not 100% why it was causing an issue, as it looked to me to be set up just fine, but removing the exceptionMappings from bootstrap fixed the issue.  If we have a need in the future to have multiple error controllers, then we'll revisit the issue.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Glad you found a solution :-)