# Unknown Null pointer exception at line ( -1 )

Tags: grails

I have the following null pointer exception, I am unable to debug that due to insufficient stack trace, the exception I am getting as following,

> Exception stack trace :
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException@3855a1c
>   className=Unknown lineNumber=-1
>   stackTrace=java.lang.NullPointerException  codeSnippet=[] gspFile=null
>   cause=java.lang.NullPointerException
>   resolver=org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver@27dee612
>   stackTraceLines=[java.lang.NullPointerException ] fileName=null
>   detailMessage=null cause=java.lang.NullPointerException stackTrace=[]
>   suppressedExceptions=[]

My application is working fine, but I'm continuously receiving this exception in email, I am not able to debug this issue, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää This is some thing strange happening in my application I cant explain it completely, no more stack trace is available to debug this, what is mean by line -1? where I have an issue?

Comment: Do some more searching.  Cut & paste your message into a Google search. 
 Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777000/grails-error-handler-always-receives-null-pointer